# 1/2/inf-Norms of A=kI

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let the matrix A of size N x N, given by A = k I, be the identity matrix of size N x N and k a strictly positive real.

How would I calculate;

-the norms (1, 2, inf) of the matrix;

-its condition number  in each of the standards 1, 2, inf

I'm truly lost. I do have the formulas of norms (1,2,inf) for a matrix, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What is the number of packaging?

Comment: It's the condition number, I don't how I could write this x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true for any norm that $\|kI\| = |k| \|I\| = k \|I\|$ (because $k>0$). It is also true for any (induced) norm that
$$
\|I\| = \sup_{x \ne 0}\dfrac{\|I x\|}{\|x\|} = \sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|x\|}{\|x\|} = 1.
$$

So, for any of these norms, or any other induced norm, $\|k I\| = |k|$.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Will it be the same for the condition number or it will change depending the norm?

Comment: It will be the same... $$cond(kI) = \|kI\| \|(kI)^{-1}\| = k \cdot \frac 1k = 1$$